# customize the last line from listview

Tags: android, listview, customization

I have a ListView that contains 1 image+2 texts + 1 image on a line. This is my xml for listview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_height="20dp"
   android:gravity="left|center"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   android:paddingRight="5dp"
   android:background="@color/list_bg"
   >

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/avatar"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       >


    <TextView android:id="@+id/listitem1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
      android:textColor="@drawable/textblack_selected"
      android:textSize="18dp"
      android:textStyle="bold" 
      />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/listitem2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="@drawable/textorange_selected"
      />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/arrowImage"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:src="@drawable/arrow_selector"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to remove the last image(the arrow) from the last line. In my adapter I tried to use this :

```
if (position == 4) lastimg.setImageResource(0);

but nothing changed.Here is my adapter:

public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < UserRecord > {
    private ArrayList < UserRecord > users;

    public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList < UserRecord > users) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, users);
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.mainmenurowlist, null);
        }

        UserRecord user = users.get(position);
        if (user != null) {
            TextView listitem1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listitem1);
            TextView listitem2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listitem2);

            if (listitem1 != null) {
                listitem1.setText(user.listitem1);
            }

            if (listitem2 != null) {
                listitem2.setText(user.listitem2);
            }
        }

        firstimg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        lastimg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.arrowImage);

        firstimg.setImageResource(FirstImage[position]);
        if (position == 4) {
            lastimg.setImageResource(0);
            System.out.println("Exit!!");
        }
        return v;
    }
}

public class UserRecord {
    public String listitem1;
    public String listitem2;

    public UserRecord(String listitem1, String listitem2) {
        this.listitem1 = listitem1;
        this.listitem2 = listitem2;
    }
}
}
```

Has anyone any idea how can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
if(position == (data_id.size()-1))
{
  lastimg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

here data_id is just an array list

or try as below

```
if(position == 4)
{
  lastimg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

both are to be same

Answer (score 0):

use this way in getView() method

```
if((users.size()-1)==position){
   // do here your stuff what u want on last item of listview
 }else{
  // do here your stuff what u want on each item of listview except last item
 }
```